# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Sub-menu carat not visible

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

We're having an issue with the mobile menu on our Wordpress driven website.

Problem:
In small viewport sizes, the carats used to expand the submenus don't show. The carats appear to be there and based on the styles are white but don't show through background. I've tried a variety of different fixes including adding "!important" to various styles without success.

Here's a screencast repro'ing the problem. 
https://www.screencast.com/t/ZbZXTegLCWa

You can also repro it by viewing the site in a browser and adjusting viewport size to 440px. 
https://www.windworkssailing.com

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example, possibly a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple viewports where these menu-arrows are not visible, because the navigation menu's width is to large.

Following viewports are affected:

- max-width: 1000px
- max-width: 768px
- max-width: 600px

Search for those media queries and for the following css element `nav.mobile_menu > ul`

Changing the `width` property to `auto` should fix the problem.

example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    nav.mobile_menu > ul {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind, that you have to change the css code at three positions since three viewports are affected.

Comment: @user135498 glad that I could help you :)